# Visual Studio 2015 - Reference by Symbolic Directory Location

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

A Visual Studio 2015 for a database project with varying schemas.  Can you please suggest a way in which I can include files from a directory referenced via an environment variable.  VS2015 - the .H files may be covered by referencing the file by environment variable  similar to $(QTDIR) from within the VS IDE.

How to handle the matching .CPP files other than importing via a directory-specific class library?

-TPeer

Answer (score 0):

I decided to create a QT Class Library to contain the schema specific functions.